# How can I animate in the entrance of a CAEmitterCell?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, caemitterlayer

Currently my particles appear on screen abruptly in their full shape and form. What I want is for the cells to either start at 0.0 opacity and animate up to full opacity, or start at 0.0 scale and animate up to 1.0 scale. I can't find anything online on how to do this.

Comment: I'd like to know this as well so I'm gonna put up a bounty on it.

Comment: did you try to use CADisplayLink?

Answer (score -1):

You can animate the various properties of a CAEmitterCell, there is a good example at [animating the CAEmitterCell Color property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961910/animating-the-caemittercell-color-property) that should give you a good idea of what you should do to get the effect you want.

There are lots of great resources on CAEmitters, one good one is [Tutorial: Particle Systems in Core Animation with CAEmitterLayer](http://enharmonichq.com/tutorial-particle-systems-in-core-animation-with-caemitterlayer/) and another is Apple's [Fireworks Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/Fireworks/Introduction/Intro.html)